# Is this the right approach to read a DOCX file from a database and open it into the current document?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I'm developing a Word Add-in (Taskpane) which the main goal is replacing some predefined content controls of documents persisted in a database. This add-in is a web app using Office.JS. Based on some user input the Add-in should get the file and open it.
My first approach based in the Office documentation was the following:

```
fetch(`/arquivo?id=${idModeloDocumento}`)
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(base64String => {

         Word.run(async context => {
             const app = context.application; 
             const doc = app.createDocument(base64String); // base64string comes from my backend app
             doc.open();
             await context.sync();
         });
     })
```

However, it opens the document on a new instance of Word App, different from the one where the add-in is already running. So I created the document and inserted each part of the document (just body and header at this context) into the current document like this:

```
fetch(`/arquivo?id=${idModeloDocumento}`)
     .then(response => response.text())
     .then(base64String => {

        Word.run(async context => {
             var base64doc = base64String
             const app = context.application
             const doc = app.createDocument(base64doc)
             await context.sync()
             console.log("Novo documento criado")

             let bodyOoxml = doc.body.getOoxml()
             let headerOoxml = doc.sections.getFirst().getHeader(Word.HeaderFooterType.primary).getOoxml()

             await context.sync()
             console.log("Preenchendo o body do documento corrente")

             let curHeader = context.document.sections.getFirst().getHeader(Word.HeaderFooterType.primary)
             curHeader.insertOoxml(headerOoxml.value, Word.InsertLocation.replace)

             let curBody = context.document.body
             curBody.insertOoxml(bodyOoxml.value, Word.InsertLocation.replace)

             await context.sync()
             console.log("Pronto")
         });                        
            
     })
```

It works, however, I'm not 100% sure if it is the right way to do that.

What's the recommended approach to open a Docx file in the current document using OfficeJS?

Comment: so you want to insert everything from the base64 file into the current document, including header/footer, right? what about if the target/current document already has header/footers?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In case the current document already has header/footer, they should be cleaned and replaced by the ones from the base64 file.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, If you want all the content inserted to the current document, you can use insertFileFromBase64 API. For this API, the header/footer from the source document may be lost in some cases, and we are trying to give enhancement to it.We will let you know if we have some progress.

Comment: Many thanks for your time! Let me know if you need more information.